# NSAppleScript sandbox entitlement for Numbers

Tags: applescript, appstore-sandbox, entitlements, nsapplescript, applescript-numbers

I'm needing to read from a Numbers spreadsheet in an App Store Sandboxed Mac app.

I have it working fine until I enable the Sandbox.

Apples docs say to use the `com.apple.security.scripting-targets` entitlement however I cannot find any entitlements for Numbers.
I can get it working using

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
<array>
    <string>com.apple.iWork.Numberss</string>
</array>
```

but I was reading that App Review will reject apps using the temporary-exception.

Is this a complete non starter, am I missing a way to get the entitlement to work with Numbers or will App Review allow it through with the temporary-exception?

Comment: Here is some information : https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/sandbox-scripting/

Comment: Thank you, that is a pretty awesome writeup.